# Windows environment variable not set if calling from a Perl script

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have a batch script `setEnv.bat` that sets environment variables like `TEST_ENV` to `true`.

I call this batch script from inside a Perl script like:

```
my $batch_cmd = "setEnv.bat";
system( $batch_cmd );
```

I run the Perl script from the command line. The `setEnv.bat` sets the environment variable. After the Perl script completes, if I do `set TEST` the output is:

> Environment variable TEST not defined.

This means that the environment variable is lost when the batch script terminated and execution continues in Perl script.

How to solve this?

Comment: Not strange. [That's how subshells work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552814/why-arent-a-batch-files-environment-variables-set-when-run-from-perl). You solve it by setting your environment they way you want it before you call your Perl script, or by manipulating `%ENV` within your Perl script.

Comment: My problem is that I have a set of batch files that I don't know what they will do - one of them might set an environment variable, one of them might run some executable - so basically my perl script is completely unaware of what's inside batch files. My perl script just runs the batch files in a sequence. The other batch files that executes executables run fine, only those which set env variables fail - the env variables are not set.  Now someone can say why don't I write a batch file that runs the sequence of batch files - I find it very hard to write a batch than to write a perl program.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the "Detect subprocess environment variables change" is exactly what I am looking for.and there is no specific answer there either. But I understand for now that perl program cannot change environment in which its running unless it is another perl program. but  voting down just for the sake it is not indented properly is not fair. In fact the description of the problem is as simple as it can be to demonstrate the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the system command will execute the first command in a shell, the second command in an another shell and so on.
This means that every shell will have its own environment and will not "see" the environment variables of the others.

If you just want a quick and dirty solution, you can try and combine commands with && , something like:

```
system('setEnv.bat && doSomething.bat');
```

It's not ideal, but if you don't want to spend too much time on it, it should work (BTW, the && should work on both Windows and Unix).

Comment: This won't work for my usecase. I have not only batch scripts but also some other kind of scripts that I want to run in a sequence. They are mixed and they need to be in an order. But thanks for your time. I am going to write my scripts using perl script primarily as utility and not as a controller ( of running the sequence of bats, exes, etc.) . My controller will be a batch file. I wish Perl has some API that solves this.

Comment: This will work as long as what you're trying to run can actually be run as a shell command. The "&&" is sequential, meaning that the second command will not be executed until the first one has been completed. An indication about what other scripts you're running (the kind of scripts) would be useful in helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Windows Perl module below in your Perl script to set Windows environment variables:

```
Win32::AdminMisc::SetEnvVar
```

Example code:

```
use Win32::AdminMisc;

$name="Temp";
$val="C:/tmp";
SetEnvVar($name,$val);
```

This will set an environmental variable $name to $val, creating $name it if does not exist. 
The new value will be set globally.
Please refer to the documentation on SetEnvVar() for further info.
The book "Win32 Perl Scripting: The Administrator's Handbook" also make a reference to SetEnvVar().

HTH

Comment: No, this is a subroutine in a Perl module (i.e. a reusable package defined in a library).  After you include the Perl module (use Win32::AdminMisc;) you would call this subroutine (SetEnvFar) from within your Perl program. I've updated the example code somewhat to make it clearer.  Please let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that module in my kit. Yes you can say I can downloaded it from www.roth.net/ but I cannot install third party without going through a lot of process in an organization. So I cannot go this route atleast for now. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are using ActiveState Perl, you can add www.roth.net to your repository and use ppm to install the package  To add it to your ppm repository use "ppm repository http://www.roth.net/perl/packages/" then install ("ppm install Win32::AdminMisc").  I believe the module is available under the Artistic License or the GPL.  Anyway, I hope I helped in some way.  :-)